# Blocking 0.0.0.0 Inbound

Tags: firewall

Is is safe to block inbound traffic with source IP 0.0.0.0/32 at my firewall box. I understand it's a non-routable IP, but it used for DHCP Discovery, so packets are not discarded with that source IP unless specified. My intent is to stop UDP floods source 0.0.0.0 from crossing from WAN to LAN.

Comment: If the interface to which this acl is attached uses DHCP, the acl will have explicitly allow DHCP before denying zero. Otherwise, yes, you should never see zero on the internet.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a firewall should block all traffic originating from the outside to the inside. It should only allow outside-originated traffic which you have explicitly configured it to allow.

Why did you allow such traffic in the first place? If you are not providing DHCP from one side of the firewall to the other, it should be fine for that traffic to be blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's exactly what Im working on. I walked in on a naked firewall, but I'm the only one it seems to bother. This client assumes that their small internet presence is obscurity enough, then they got hit. Now I'm here working on a firewall though I'm more adept in R&S.

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly block that, you just need to remove the rule allowing it. A firewall defaults to blocking everything except what you have configured it to allow.

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 is great for egresss and GateWay of last resort, however you can only imagine the bad things that could ensue when any traffic was allowed to pass through the FW looking for its "path" kind of defeats the purpose of the device.